# Python route usage

Tags: python, django

How can I use $ in the python url .

This is my usage

```
   from django.urls import include, path
   from vote import views
   urlpatterns = [
      path(r'^$', views.index, name='index') 
   ]
```

but it ending with

Using the URLconf defined in election.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='index']
vote/ ^$ [name='index']

I need to get understand what is the best usage

Comment: Use `re_path()` instead of `path()` if you want to have regular expression characters like `^$`.

Comment: FWIW: `$` should be used as a sub delimiter, see the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).